# Override php.ini settings on entry point

Tags: php, apache

On a shared business environment the service provider has a `php.ini` somewhere on the directory of the PHP interpreter. We must override some settings, but those you are not able to change runtime with `ini_set`. For example: `magic-quotes-gpc`. Of course, `ini_set` returns with `FALSE` this case, since there would be no point changing the `magic-quotes-gpc`, the client's input already has been processed.

I've found out that, I can place a different `php.ini` file near my entry point, for example into the same directory where `index.php` lives. Having a `php.ini` there with the following content:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = OFF
```

I'm getting a `PDO not found` instantly. It seems the original `php.ini` is getting discarded this way. How can I make it not to swap, but to override the original `php.ini`?

Comment: Replicate the whole php.ini then (including the possibly missing extension=/usr/... entries), only change the fields that need to be overridden. Alternatively a `.user.ini` gets applied in conjunction typically.

Comment: magic quotes should *always* be switched off. It causes security holes that hackers can drive a bus through. It's deprecated as of PHP 5.3, and the feature has been removed entirely in the most recent PHP versions. Anyone who still thinks they should be switching it on is in urgent need of a rethink. (and if your server provider has it switched on by default then you need to find a better service provider)

Comment: Right, I'm trying to switch it off, actually. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to override the setting using a .htaccess file, if you run Apache.

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

Comment: Is there anything more to add to this? I've tried it right now, and got an `Internal Server Error`.

Comment: It should work, might be that your server does not allow .htaccess files or does not allow the php_flag directive in them.

Comment: `.htaccess` files are allowed. `php_flag` should be the problem there. Any alternative?

Comment: I've found a recursive script, that is equivalent to not to have `magic_quotes_gpc` switched on. This makes my problem specific to this attribute, but I accept your answer to this question.